# SCRIPT GMAIL : Import only the text in parentheses in subject

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I want to create en event from a specific mail I'm receiving.
Inside the subject of the mail, inside parenthese there is the date for the event.

I try to import the specific text contained in the subject of the gmail message.

The global subject is : EDF - Tempo : demain jour ROUGE (mercredi 10 janvier 2024)
I just want to import the text inside the parentheses id est: mercredi 10 janvier 2024

I don't know how to do that

I try to use :

subject.split("(")

But the end parenthese comes with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RegEx to find text within parentheses. The pattern `/\(.+\)/` will just grab all text from the first `(` until the last `)` but it will work for the provided example.

```js
function getTextInParentheses(text) {
  return /\(.+\)/.exec(text)[0].slice(1, -1) // Return inner text
}

const subject = "EDF - Tempo : demain jour ROUGE (mercredi 10 janvier 2024)"
const date = getTextInParentheses(subject)

console.log(date) // mercredi 10 janvier 2024
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can control what's on the subject then you can use slice:

```
function senttestemail() {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(gobj.globals.emailpriv,"EDF - Tempo : demain jour ROUGE (text to find)","This is a test.")
}

function findEmailText() {
  const ts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  ts.forEach(t => t.getMessages().forEach(m => {
    if(m.getSubject().includes("EDF - Tempo : demain jour ROUGE")){
      Logger.log(m.getSubject().slice(33,-1))
    }
  }))
}

Execution log
10:13:06 AM Notice  Execution started
10:13:07 AM Info    text to find
10:13:09 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)